# tslint no var keyword how to push array?

Tags: mongodb, typescript, dynamic-programming, tslint

I am using Typescript/MongoDB

I want like this Object Array 
make ArrayResult use MongoDB Dynamic Query.

```
var query: QueryObj[];
subList.forEach((sub, idx) => {
    const obj: QueryObj = { title: sub.title, ep: { $gt: sub.ep } };
    query.push(obj);
});
```

But tslint can't make var.

How can I only use "let or const" dynamic query

The tslint message is

> message: 'Forbidden 'var' keyword, use 'let' or 'const' instead
>   (no-var-keyword)' source: 'tslint'

Comment: Use `const` instead of `var`.

Comment: `query` isn't initialized either. `const query: QueryObj[] = [];`

Comment: That code is hideous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your tslint file there is a rule set to nit use var keyword so you have only two options either you remove that rule or use let or const. let can be reassigned but not const.